# preimage of a pointwise limit of continuous functions and a $G_\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let be a sequence of pointwise convergent, and continuous functions $f_n : M \to 
 \mathbb {R}$ , where M is a metric space.  Prove that  $\forall c\in \mathbb R$ , the set $ f^{-1} ([c,\infty ))$ is a $ G_\delta$.  Where $ f$ $=$ lim $f_n$

First I know that every $f_n^{-1} ([c,\infty ))$ is closed, since each $f_n$ is continuous. I don't know how to relate that sets and the set $f^{-1} ([c,\infty ))$ . I only noticed one thing and it´s this equality.

$$
f^{ - 1} \left( {\left[ {c,\infty } \right)} \right) \supset \bigcap\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {f_n ^{ - 1} \left( {\left( {c - \frac{1}
{n},\infty } \right)} \right)} 
$$
or instead of $
{\left( {c - \frac{1}
{n},\infty } \right)}
$ we can consider $
{\left( {\left( {c - h\left( n \right),\infty } \right)} \right)}
$ where $h(n)$ it's any positive sequence such that converges to zero.
With this I can only conclude that this set contains a $ G_\delta$ but nothing else :(

EDIT: And I also proved that these two sets , not necesarly are equal. For example consider $
f_n \left( x \right) = \frac{x}
{n}
$ and the interval $[-1,\infty)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $f(x) \ge c$ iff for every positive integer $n$ there is $m$ such that $m > n$ and 
$f_m(x) > c - 1/n$.

Comment: I did it thx for your advice